Concerns over ceiling cracks?
The house was remodeled about 2 years ago and they removed the outdated can lighting and replaced with more LED pucks -- essentially reconfiguring where all the lights were. There are 3-4 cracks appearing where these new lights were installed, all perpendicular to one another. I'm assuming they cut strips of sheetrock instead of patching individually. Normal movement or something more concerning? Is there an easy cosmetic fix (if that's all it turns out to be)?
The added reason for concern is they did remove a load-bearing wall but replaced it with a steel beam that passed inspection and engineers.
https://imgur.com/a/NtAyDJ7

With the inspection and engineer, I suspect just normal settling cracks with the new beam, unless someone goofed up.  Is it possible those cracks line up with the ceiling joists/roof trusses?  It does not take much movement for drywall to crack.

Yeah, that's probably where the drywall was repaired after installing the beam.  I'd consider caulking the cracks (for a more flexible finish) and painting.  Although the register being there is odd.  Can you poke an inspection camera between the duct and drywall to see what's up in there?
